# Cannot call the same static method from identical method from the same class

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, controller

I have this error controller in my Codeigniter 2.1.0 application:

```
<?php

class Error extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        set_status_header(404);
        $data->menuItems = Main::_menu();
        $data->title = "404 error !";
        $data->pageview = 'templates/404';
        $this->load->view('templates/main', $data);
    }

    public function facebook()
    {

        set_status_header(404);            
        $data->menuItems = Main::_menu();
        $data->title = "Facebook error !";
        $data->pageview = "templates/facebook_error";
        $this->load->view('templates/main', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

The Maincontroller _menu:

```
<?php
class Main extends CI_Controller
{
    // ...  a lot of methods here ...
    public static function _menu()
    {
            static $menuItems = array( //just a simple array
                                     );
    }
}
?>
```

facebook() method is totally the same as the index(), however index works fine, facebook() throw this message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Main' not found in /var/www/MYApplicationName/application/controllers/error.php on line 22
```

How the earth is that possible ? How can I reach `Main::_menu()` from facebook() method ?

Comment: Is the MainController file included? The error means that it cannot find the class, often because the class file isn't included within the script.

Comment: This is the whole Error class. No additional code is in the index() method. How is that possible if these two are the same but one cannot call what the other can ? Or is index() method a special one ? and yeah, I know how to include something, but my question is how is it possible that index() works ???

Comment: the usual codeigniter place `application/controllers/main.php`

Comment: That's intriguing behavior indeed, there should be no difference for CI class loader (but it apparently is). May I suggest the other way around: implementing your `menu` as a view helper?

Comment: hmm :D you mean the whole function or how ? I was even asking this one time here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11277/where-to-put-menu-items-in-mvc-with-php-model-or-controller

Comment: do you have to call parent constructor in main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @TheShiftExchange's answer, I was able to track down that a route setting caused this behaviour. My `config/routes.php` looks like this:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'error/index';
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

So, when I made a request to `www.example.com/nonexistent-url` this get served by the `main` controller, then CI noticed that there is no method like this so it ran `error/index` too, but the `main` controller was already loaded by then.

The other method `facebook` was redirected from an existing method of `main` only, for example `gallery`, this way it is like if I went to the url `www.example.com/error/facebook`, so the `main` controller is not loaded, because only `error/facebook` is requested. If I call `www.example.com/error/index` it works the same, because in this case the `main` controller is not loaded, only the `error`.

(The bounty goes to @TheShiftExchange, because his answer was the most accurate and provided me the best information to able track down the problem. Thanks !
One of my redirect was never reached, which I tought was calling the error/index page.)

Answer (score 1):

Calling functions from another controller breaks MVC and puts you in the HMVC realm.

Please take a look at [this thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/55212/), and also CodeIgniter's [Modular Extensions (HMVC) Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) if you really need to do this.

Comment: Good topic, thanks. i think I got answer to my old question in this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11277/where-to-put-menu-items-in-mvc-with-php-model-or-controller

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create MY_Controller which extends the CI_Controller where you put your reusable code?

Answer (score 1):

Actually - you are mistaken. Your "index" code does not work either.

I just pasted all your code above into a clean version of CI 2.1.2 and the index function ALSO returns the same error.

So perhaps your computer has something cached, or you have some other code elsewhere that is making you think it is working. But it does not work.

Anyway - the *real question* is why are you trying to call a controller from another controller? That is not a good MVC approach. Your "_menu()" function should be located in a [library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) - that is where it belongs.

Or put the _menu() code into "MY_Controller" and have both controllers extend [MY_Controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html).

Or put the _menu() code into a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html).

Basically there are three better ways you could approach this.

Comment: best answer so far, I check it, maybe caching was the reason... Also thanks for the suggestions, I already put menu in to a model.